# Drawing a simple non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA)

Tags: computation-theory, formal-languages, automaton

How can I draw NFA (automaton) for this question?

First it should accept:

- alphabet = x,y,z
- L= { w | w such that, one of the number of occurrence x,y,z is multiple of three. }

For example: {xxx, yyy, zzz, xyxyzzz, xyxyx, zyzyz...}

Comment: I can only think about it dfa position. ε moves it is really complicated for me. i dont really find a solution now

Comment: @Knaas: Isn't it homework? it certainly looks like it. If it is - please do not remove the `homework` tag.

Comment: even if it is, i cant do that, i cant find a solution about it.

Answer (score 2):

First let's start with the simpler question:

How would you draw this automaton for L' = {a<sup>n</sup> | n % 3 == 0}?

You'd draw an automaton with 3 states - one for each possible modolus, and iterate between them for each appearance of `a`. The accepting state will be the one denoted for `0`.

Now, after establishing that - for your problem, you need to have 3<sup>3</sup> states for your automaton - all possible tuples for `(x,y,z)` where x,y,z are in {0,1,2}.

Your goal now is to understand What will your lamda be? Since it is your homework, I won't give the complete answer, only a hint:

If you see `x` and you are in state `(a,b,c)` - you want to advance to `(a+1 %3 ,b,c)`

Also think - what are the accepting states? hint: what was the accepting state for the simplified `L'`?

**attachment**: automaton for `L'` as described above.

[image: L' automaton]

Comment: :S I have difficulty to understand your response sorry for that. :/

Comment: @Knaas: Which part exactly don't you understand? Do you understand how to draw automaton for the simplified `L'`?

Comment: @Knaas: Have a look at the edit - I added a draw of the automaton for `L'` - once you understand it - continue and read how to create an automaton for your more complex `L`

Comment: i minimized the dfa, i have converted the nfa to dfa. i really dont nfa drawing by myself. i cant decide where to begin you give me some  information :s

Comment: @Knaas: I don't understand your question. If you already have a DFA - changing DFA to NFA is trivial [the same draw also holds for NFA!]